# How can I have a generic doOnError after exception class specific ones in Reactor

Tags: java, reactor

It feels like this should be simple, so I might be missing something obvious.
I have a simple example case where I have an error Mono, and I would like to have exception class specific handling with a generic handler.

```
    Mono.error(new RuntimeException())
            .doOnError(RuntimeException.class, e -> System.out.println("Caught RuntimeException"))
            .doOnError(Throwable.class, e -> System.out.println("Caught Throwable"))
            .block();

output: Caught RuntimeException
        Caught Throwable
```

The problem is that both consumers will get called (the one with RuntimeException and the generic one with Throwable). Is there a (clean) way to avoid calling the generic one if a more specific one was already called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a way to recover from an error, use [onErrorResume](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#onErrorResume-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Function-) function instead.

```
Mono.error(new RuntimeException())
    .flatMap(k -> callExternalService(k)
        .onErrorResume(RuntimeException.class, this::recoverFromRuntimeExeption)
        .onErrorResume(Throwable.class, this::recoverFromThrowable)
    );
```

This way you'll change the execution path of your Mono from error to success and subsequent `doOnError` won't be called.

Comment: This would be a solution to the problem, but I still need to maintain the execution path with the error, because later on I have generic error handling logic. What I would like to do here is have some 'cleanup' steps after a failed attempt, but still keep the error mono.I will still accept this as an answer, because it solves the issue that I presented, I should have been more specific.